# Prevent an embedded iframe from being accessible outside the app, even in other tabs?

Tags: javascript, security, nginx, iframe

I'm developing a web application and need to embed an iframe that contains sensitive information. **I want to ensure that this iframe is only accessible within the context of my application and cannot be accessed from other browser tabs or externally even when the user is authenticated**.

I've considered using the "sandbox" attribute, "X-Frame-Options" header, and "Content Security Policy (CSP)" to restrict iframe behavior. Specifically, in my nginx.conf file, I've set up the following configurations:

1. CSP:

```
add_header Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors http://127.0.0.1:5500;";
```

This restricts iframe embedding to only the 127.0.0.1:5500 host.

2. X-Frame-Options:

```
add_header X-Frame-Options "ALLOW-FROM http://127.0.0.1:5500";
```

NGINX confg:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    add_header Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors http://127.0.0.1:5500;";
    add_header X-Frame-Options "ALLOW-FROM http://127.0.0.1:5500";
    location / {
        index index.html;
    }

}
```

While these configurations help restrict the iframe from being embedded on other sites, I've noticed that the embedded application can still be accessed directly using the iframe's source URL(ie.localhost:8080/).

Is there a way to completely prevent access to the embedded iframe, ensuring it can only be interacted with and viewed within my application's context? If not, what additional security measures can I take to make it as difficult as possible for unauthorized access?

IFRAME html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- <meta http-equiv="X-Frame-Options" content="SAMEORIGIN"> -->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="frame-ancestors http://127.0.0.1:5500;">
    <meta http-equiv="Referrer-Policy" content="no-referrer">
    <title>Secure App</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>My Secure App</h1>
    <p>This is a secure web application.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx
COPY iframe-nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY index.html /etc/nginx/html/index.html
```

Parent Html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>iframe</div>
    <iframe src="http://localhost:8080/" sandbox="allow-same-origin"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In general, iframes can only be accessed from other windows/tabs in the same domain.